# 404 error at JS single page site after refresh page

Tags: javascript, nginx, http-status-code-404

I have nginx and JS single page  site.
I have 404 error after  refresh page "mysite.com/user". it`s page work when firstuse, but after page refresh nginx return 404 error.

```
[error] 30149#0: *45 open() "/var/www/users" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: , server: mysite.com, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"`
```

Please help.

site conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com;
    root    /var/www/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
    }

    location /static/ {
        add_header Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    }

    location /index.html {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }

    location /config.json {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

I am do not understanding why it is work(

Answer (score 0):

You need to match `/user` URI. Use a custom location or use 
`location / {
    rewrite (.*) index.html break;
}`

Use it at end, else it will break your `/static/` location

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

For further info [check](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)

Comment: I use  `try_files  '' $uri $uri/ /index.html`; and  `try_files   $uri $uri/ =404`; but see 404 error after page refresh